# Creature "sees" not with light but metal ions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

What is the short story (By Arthur C Clarke?) where a creature "sees" mercury vapor from a flare. I think it takes place on an asteroid; a man fleeing pursuit uses the creature to surprise and delay his pursuers.

Comment: Off to a good start, but you could maybe suggest when you'd read it and when the story may have been published. Also if it was in an anthology, maybe you remember some of the other stories? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) for some help on [edit]ing in more details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Uncommon Sense](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45642)" by Hal Clement.

[image]

The crab/centipede-like creatures that live in on the airless planetoid have ball-shaped eyes with a small opening to let the ions in (for directional sensing).  The protagonist exploits this to defeat the space pirates that have hijacked his ship - he attracts the crab-like creatures by setting a trap with the metallic body "fluids" of their prey. It boils off when the pirates begin to work on that part of the ship with a welder, and the creatures attack them, attracted by the ions that are released.

Full story posted [here](http://www.prosperosisle.org/spip.php?article864) - unknown if legitimately so.

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you. I'm teaching high school bio, and hope to use this and other stories to expand students outlook and emphasize basic principles, to get them thinking outside the box.

Comment: You're welcome.  Wish I had taken your class back in the day!